# What are gradle task definitions in groovy language?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm completely new to both gradle and groovy and I'm having trouble to find information about what the below actually is in the groovy language

```
task myTask(dependsOn: 'compile') << {
   println 'I am not affected'
}
```

AFAIK the `{...}` part is a closure which seems to be passed to whatever is defined before `<<`.

Is `task myTask()` a call to a constructor?

And what is the thing with the colon that looks like a parameter?

What does `<<` do? Is it an operator that was overloaded by gradle or is it standard groovy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dependsOn: 'compile'` is a named argument. `<<` is an overloaded operator that adds a *task action* to the task. (See [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for more information.) `{ ... }` is a closure that implements the task action. `myTask` is syntactically a nested method call (`task(myTask(dependsOn: 'compile') << ...)`), but gets rewritten to a String using a Groovy compiler plugin (`task('myTask', dependsOn: 'compile') << ...`).

Comment: Project  has a mehod: task(Map<String,?> args, String name),  rather than  task(String name, Map<String,?> args) .   So it should be task( dependsOn: 'compile', 'myTask') << ...

Comment: Thanks Peter for the pointer. Is that Groovy compiler plugin's behaviour described somehere, or do you perhaps have a link to its sourcecode?