# gradle task method syntax in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am new to gradle and groovy,I am reading the usr guide of Gradle, and have some syntax questions on task method:

```
task intro(dependsOn: hello) {
   doLast { println "I'm Gradle" }  
}
```

Question 1:in above code, which method is called in `Project` API ? I know there are four overload in API:

```
Task task(String name, Closure configureClosure);
Task task(Map<String, ?> args, String name, Closure configureClosure);
Task task(Map<String, ?> args, String name) throws InvalidUserDataException;
Task task(String name) throws InvalidUserDataException;
```

but the parameter such as `intro(dependsOn: hello)` or `copy(type: Copy)` make me confused, what it should be if add parentheses?

Question 2: why << is shorthand for `doLast` method? I mean there is a  `leftshift` method in `Task` API ? what is diff between them?

Question 3: why can use `tasks.create()` method in build.gradle [17.1. Defining tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N1110C),I did not see `tasks` property in `Project` API or in `AbstractProject` source code.

Comment: I know there are some similar question [What are gradle task definitions in groovy language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592504/what-are-gradle-task-definitions-in-groovy-language/25592665#25592665),but still I wish can find more answer about these

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case:

```
task intro(dependsOn: hello) {
   doLast { println "I'm Gradle" }  
}
```

the following method will be invoked:

```
Task task(Map<String, ?> args, String name, Closure configureClosure);
```

Since gradle uses a specific DSL it may be hard to tell but:

1. Q1

   - `intro` is a `String name` argument
   - `dependsOn: hello` which is equivalent to `[dependsOn: hello]` (a `Map`) is `Map<String, ?> args`
   - `{ doLast { println "I'm Gradle" } }` is `Closure configureClosure`
2. Q2

`<<` is a shorthand for `doLast` just to make it more concise. You can use `doLast`, `<<`, `leftShift` - it's all the same. `leftShift` is overridden - see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#leftShift(groovy.lang.Closure))

3. Q3

There's no such method `tasks` but `getTasks`, see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getTasks()). This is how groovy works - if method is a getter `()` and `get` can be omitted, so `project.getTasks()` is equivalent to `project.tasks`.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's very helpful. I found the gradle syntax are diff from groovy syntax, and the task method in build.gradle are resolved in [`TaskDefinitionScriptTransformer`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/internal/TaskDefinitionScriptTransformer.java)

Comment: @VincentHsiung, yes, that's true. Gradle uses a dedicated DSL which is utilizes groovy. If you found ma answer helpful please accept it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, got a few questions:
1. why there is no comma to separate the arguments, i remember groovy needs it
2. why the order does not match, the signature required args then the name
3. is groovy in gradle using the same syntax as "normal" groovy