# what does the groovy compiler make of gradle dependsOn syntax

Tags: gradle, groovy

I understand that the gradle DSL

```
task doTask { logger.info "some text" }
```

will actually call the method task(String,Closure) on the Project delegate object. It's more or less a short hand for

```
task("doTaks", {logger.info("some text")})
```

That's all fine. But things get complicated when I try to understand some gradle DSL syntax I've seen in third party build scripts:

```
task doTask (dependsOn: 'otherTask'){logger.info "some text"}
```

I figure that groovy will create a map from (dependsOn: 'otherTask'), and that somehow the Project method

```
task(Map args, String name, Closure config)
```

will be called. But how do these additional parentheses come into play, why are they necessary, how does groovy figure out what we want here? The syntax looks totally counter-intuitive to me with my minimal groovy skill. I would never guess that I have to do it this way to make it work.

So, that's the question: how does groovy figure out what to do with this command:

```
task doTask (dependsOn: 'otherTask'){ // some code }
```

Comment: Gradle build scripts in groovy are a DSL, not plain groovy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627258/gradle-task-method-syntax-in-build-gradle

Comment: @tim_yates: thanks for linking to the other question. The answers there do not add anything new to my question, so I would not consider it a duplicate though the difference is really in the nuances. Marco R.'s response below actually solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke groovy methods using one the following syntaxes:

1. Args must be all comma separated within parenthesis:

   ```
    method(arg1, arg2, ..., argN, argClosure)
   ```
2. Args must be all comma separated without parenthesis:

   ```
    method arg1, arg2, ..., argN, argClosure
   ```
3. If the last argument is a closure, all previous args must be all comma separated within parenthesis, and the code block (within braces `{...}`) following the closing parenthesis will be interpreted as the last [`Closure`](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) argument `argClosure`:

   ```
    method(arg1, arg2, ..., argN) { ... }
   ```

   If you **DO NOT** want the code block within the curly braces to be interpreted as a `Closure` argument for the preceding method invocation; then end the method invocation with a semicolon:

   ```
    // Because of `;` following { ... } is not a Closure argument for `method`
    method(arg1, arg2, ..., argN); { ... }
   ```
4. A method that accepts as an argument a single `Map` or a `Map` and a closure, may be invoked using the [*named parameters*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.0-beta-1/html/documentation/#_named_argument_constructor) syntax; which will transform each *named* argument into an entry in the map and the last argument will be a closure. This will create the following intuitive syntactic variants:

   ```
    method(name1: arg1, name2: arg2, ..., nameN: argN, argClosure)
    method name1: arg1, name2: arg2, ..., nameN: argN, argClosure
    method(name1: arg1, name2: arg2, ..., nameN: argN) { ... }
   ```

Groovy provides tons of syntactic sugar, so other intuitive variants can be found around this; but this gives you the feeling for groovy's way of handling `Closure` arguments.

The following is a working demo of these different ways of doing a method invocation:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

def handleWithClosure(data1, data2, closure) {
    closure("$data1. $data2")
}

def logger = { println "${LocalDateTime.now()} - $it" }
handleWithClosure(1, 'All within parenthesis', logger)
handleWithClosure 2, 'All without parenthesis', logger
handleWithClosure(3, 'List of arguments within parenthesis and closure outside') { logger(it) }

def handleMapWithClosure(map, closure) {
    handleWithClosure(map['num'], "[Named Arguments/Map based] ${map['msg']}", closure)
}

handleMapWithClosure(msg: 'All within parenthesis', num: 1, logger)
handleMapWithClosure msg: 'All without parenthesis', num: 2, logger
handleMapWithClosure(msg: 'List of arguments within parenthesis and closure outside', num: 3) { logger(it) }
```

Running it you can see how it is treating all these syntactic options.

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/groovy/so/a56203192)

Hope this helps.